# Destructuring assignment to assign styles to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

JavaScript has a nifty [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) short hand feature that works well when creating multiple variables from properties in an object.

I want to do something similar with the styles for a button element. Here is my working code:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.style.background = '#30a900';
button.style.color = 'white';
button.style.border = '1px solid white';
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
var mystyles = {
    background: '#30a900',
    color: 'white',
    border: '1px solid white',
};
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.style = mystyles;
```

However, this doesn't work as expected. Is there a feature of ES6 to do this assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)?

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = 'Object.assign';
var mystyles = {
    background: '#30a900',
    color: 'white',
    border: '1px solid white',
};
Object.assign(button.style, mystyles);
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const button = document.createElement('button');
Object.assign(button.style, {
  background: '#30a900',
  color: 'white',
  border: '1px solid white',
});
```

Example:

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');
Object.assign(button.style, {
  background: '#30a900',
  color: 'white',
  border: '1px solid white',
});
button.textContent = 'Button';
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```